# Database modeling tool

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a simple tool to draw up my database in. I know that i saw one that was made in C# on Codeproject but i can't find that one.
I just need to be able to visually draw my tables and relations for MS SQLServer 2008.

Comment: Try [SqlDBM](http://sqldbm.com), it is  very nice tool, has tons of handy features. It is online tool, absolutely free with great UI. I use it all the time for my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [SQL Power Architect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect) for the following reasons (from the official feature list):

- Accesses source databases via JDBC
- Connects to multiple source databases concurrently
- Compares data models & database structures and identifies discrepancies
- Drag-and-drop source tables & columns into the playpen
- Remembers the origin of each column
- Generates source-to-target visual Mapping Reports
- Forward/reverse engineers PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server & more
- Saves source data structure snapshots in the project, so you can work remotely
- All project data is stored in an easy-to-parse XML format
- OLAP schema modeling: Cubes, Measures, Dimensions, Hierarchies & Levels
- GPL (version 3) licensed

...and a couple reasons of my own:

- runs on basically any platform
- has fairly nice keyboard support for fast model development
- relatively useful diagram auto-layout

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not want to use the built-in Data Diagrammer?

If you just want to *draw* your tables, have a look at [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/). In the Links section you find some tools that convert the drawing into SQL.