# database design tool question

Tags: database, database-design

is there a good database design tool can generate sql script to create database (tables) in major database (Oracle, MySQL, SQL server, Sybase) without any changes?

Which design tool are you think is good.

Comment: Please, check out [database design functionality](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/oracle-query-builder.html) build in dbForge Studio for Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [Power Architect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect), for the same reasons I listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423863/database-modeling-tool/2423882#2423882) question:

- Accesses source databases via JDBC
- Connects to multiple source databases concurrently
- Compares data models & database structures and identifies discrepancies
- Drag-and-drop source tables & columns into the playpen
- Remembers the origin of each column
- Generates source-to-target visual Mapping Reports
- Forward/reverse engineers PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server & more
- Saves source data structure snapshots in the project, so you can work remotely
- All project data is stored in an easy-to-parse XML format
- OLAP schema modeling: Cubes, Measures, Dimensions, Hierarchies & Levels
- GPL (version 3) licensed

...and a couple reasons of my own:

- runs on basically any platform
- has fairly nice keyboard support for fast model development
- relatively useful diagram auto-layout

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Datanamic's](http://www.datanamic.com/) DeZign for Databases with success.  It's a graphical interface that can generate the scripts for almost every major database.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Enterprise Architect. I use it for all of my design UML based use cases, Architectural views, class/collaboration diagrams and database schema. Its great. One can generate script very easilly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider using the UML2DB SQL generation service:

http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml2db-full-code-generation-sql-scripts-databases

Choose your UML tool (e.g. ArgoUML), draw a class diagram, (optional) configure some code-generation options in the web interface and it's done. Forget about using stereotypes or profiles. Let the service use common-sense to do the generation for you. All major database vendors supported.