# Is there any SQL Server database designer software like MySQL workbench?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I need to design database for SQL Server, is there any MySQL workbench like software for that? I have access to MSDN, so it can also be commercial product that can be found form MSDN.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419276/data-modeling-tool-for-sql-server

Comment: See this question for answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419276/data-modeling-tool-for-sql-server

Comment: and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509051/database-design-tool-question
and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423863/database-modeling-tool
and probably many more...

Comment: Have you tried SqlDBM ? It is one of the best tools I have found so far after researching many (like Erwin, Vertabelo etc) , SqlDMB has tons of handy features. It is online tool, absolutely free with very friendly UI. Give it a try: https://sqldbm.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL Server ships with [SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) which is probably what most SQL developers use to develop in T-SQL and do basic schema management.

There are also a myriad of third party products like the following:
http://www.sql-workbench.net/

Comment: and for some tasks, nothing is quicker then a MS-Access ADP !   
e.g: duplicate a table using ^c, ^v

Answer (score 1):

The software that corresponds best to MySQL Workbench is [Microsoft SQL Server Query Analyzer](http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/tutorial/sql_query_analyzer.cfm). In my opinion its a great product, superb for developing and testing SQL queries. It's stable as a rock. Alike MySQL Workbench it sports a tabbed interface. One nice feature is that if you write multiple queries in one tab you get the corresponding number of outputs, all in the same tab.

Comment: no diagraming in mssqa